# Make histogram with data range in HighchartJS

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an array like this:

```
data ={ [1547078400000,1],
        [1547164800000,7],
        [1547251200000,19],
        [1547337600000,9],
        [1547424000000,13],
        [1547596800000,1],
        [1547683200000,5],
        [1547769600000,2],
        [1547942400000,1],
        [1548115200000,1],
        [1548201600000,1],
        [1548892800000,1],
        [1549152000000,4],
        [1549238400000,2],
        [1549324800000,4],
        [1549411200000,6],
        [1549497600000,1],
        [1549584000000,10],
        [1549670400000,4]
}
```

There, first column is date in timestamp, and second column is value corresponding to this date.

I want to create histogram with data range, thus an x-axis is values's axis, and y-axis - is amount of such values in specified data range.
Llike in the picture(but without dots):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please create jsfiddle

Comment: Please notice that Histogram series calculates how many data points exist in some y value range, not how many data points exist in some time range. The implementation of your data looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j2a7vd6u/

Comment: I want exactly distribution over the time.. loos like I need processing Y-data when data range selector is updated, is there any event handler?

Comment: Processing y-data is not a good solution either, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p7y5sauf/

Comment: I think that using `dataGrouping` will be a better approach to achieve your requirement. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping